# jQuery order elements, remove, detach, clone, append memory leaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a parent div with around 300 div's inside its all containing an image and some text. i have an array which contains all the information i need to reorder the divs, using references..

if if then loop through the array after i had ordered it and then move the elements accordinly i get severe memory leaks of up to 100MB extra time i sort them!

i have tried a few ways and still no success

```
$.each(gameArray , function($idx, $itm) { 
    $("#elementid"+ $itm.split('|#|')[0] ).appendTo($("#parent"));
});
```

another attempt

```
$.each(gameArray , function($idx, $itm) { 
    var element = $("#elementid"+ $itm.split('|#|')[0] ).detach();
    element.appendTo($("#parent"));
    element = null;
});
```

another attempt

```
$.each(gameArray , function($idx, $itm) { 
    var element = $("#elementid"+ $itm.split('|#|')[0] ).clone(true).remove();
    element.appendTo($("#parent"));
    element = null;
});
```

i read that the detach keeps the element in DOM so when you put it back into the page it doesnt recreate anything and doesn't increase the memory, but it doesnt seem to work?!

is there something im missing? there must be a way of sorting them without increasing memory by that much?

All of the example i have found have been using ordered list's with around 10 list elements in so you dont notice the memory increase!

Comment: Have you tried moving the dom elements without jQuery? Maybe the constant creation of jquery objects is a problem?!

Comment: not yet! ill have a look now and post my findings!

Comment: var parent = document.getElementById('game_panel');
    $.each(koko.data('newGameArray'), function($idx, $itm) { 
     var element = document.getElementById('gameidis'+$itm.split('|#|')[0]);
     parent.appendChild(element.parentNode.removeChild(element));
    });

using standard javascript causes the same leaks!

Comment: @RoryPickering That's still not standard JavaScript. `$.each(..)` is also a jQuery method.

Comment: @RobW oh yeah!!! it appears as though it is only the manipulation of the divs that is causing the leek though! im just about to try the method posted below by dgilland!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At heavy (DOM) operations where performance issues are encountered, you should completely drop jQuery, and go back to vanilla JavaScript (especially if the no-jQuery alternative works across all modern browsers).

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); // Temporary storage
for (var $idx=0, len = gameArray.length; $idx<len; $idx++) {
    var $itm = $gameArray[$idx];
    fragment.appendChild(
        document.getElementById("elementid" + $itm.split('|#|', 1)[0] )
    );
}
// Append all items to parent
document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(fragment);
```

The used methods are:

- [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)-loop.
- [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) ( *identifier* )
- [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) ( *separator*, *limit* )
- [`document.createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3adocument.createDocumentFragment)

Comment: thanks for your reply but im still having memory leaks with this example... if i  remove the code that actually stores the element in the fragmenet and appends it, it doesn't leak memory, so it is deifnalty not any of the other code! weird!

Comment: yeah i understand, just done a quick test, and it appears to be the images, if i strip out the img tag from each div the memory usage doesn't go up! each image is only aroun 100 x 75 but without them in the memory stays the same! maybe you cant store a img in fragmented memory?!

Comment: >_> There's nothing wrong with the DOM. The images are loaded in the memory.

Comment: if i have the images in the divs, when i reorder, firefox's memory usage goes up, if i dont have the images in the divs, the memory usage stays the same. using the method you posted above

Comment: apologies Rob, it wasn't images. it was hidden iFrames!

Comment: In the future, add (a link to) the code in your question. That will lead to the right answer more quickly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="0">0</div>
    <div id="1">1</div>
    <div id="2">2</div>
    <div id="3">3</div>
    <div id="4">4</div>
    <div id="5">5</div>
    <div id="6">6</div>
    <div id="7">7</div>
    <div id="8">8</div>
    <div id="9">9</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var games = [ 4, 3, 0, 2, 5, 1, 6, 9, 7, 8 ]; // desired sort order

var $parent = $('#parent');
var $children = $parent.children('div');

$children.detach().sort(function(a,b){
    var aId = parseInt( $(a).attr('id'), 10 );
    var bId = parseInt( $(b).attr('id'), 10 )
    return games.indexOf(aId) > games.indexOf(bId);
});

$parent.append($children);
```

This detaches your children, sorts them, and then appends them back to the parent which avoids modifying the DOM during the sort process.

Comment: i still seem to be getting the same memory leak with this method!?